# Struggling to Convert Varchar to Float

Tags: sql, sql-server

I Googled this before posting.  It seems like my code below should easily cast varchar to float, but I keep getting this error:

```
Error converting data type varchar to float.
```

SQL:

```
SELECT CORP.Desc1
      ,CORP.TICKER
      ,CORP.CPN
      ,CORP.MATURITY
      ,CORP.NAME
      ,CORP.RTG_SP
      ,GS.SECURITY_DES
      ,CAST(GS.BVAL_BID_PRICE AS FLOAT) AS BID
      ,CAST(GS.BVAL_ASK_PRICE AS FLOAT) AS ASK
      ,(GS.BVAL_ASK_PRICE AS FLOAT - GS.BVAL_BID_PRICE AS FLOAT) AS Spread
FROM [CORP] AS CORP
INNER JOIN [BULK_GS] AS GS
ON CORP.Desc1 = GS.ID_ISIN
```

Comment: You have data in the column that can't be converted.  Use TRY_CAST to find it.

Comment: You can do `select distinct bval_bid_price from gs order by 1` and see if any of the data can't be converted - just like Tab mentioned above. You can also use `case when bval_bid_price is null then null else cast(...) end as bid` to just keep null values null and not do casting on them.

Comment: To identify rows that are storing invalid values (which you could avoid by using the right data type for the column in the first place), use `SELECT * FROM dbo.BULK_GS WHERE (BVAL_ASK_PRICE IS NOT NULL AND TRY_CONVERT(float, BVAL_ASK_PRICE) IS NULL) OR (BVAL_BID_PRICE IS NOT NULL AND TRY_CONVERT(float, BVAL_BID_PRICE) IS NULL);`

Answer (score 0):

Use a conditional block if you are using `convert()` or use `try_convert()`.

```
select data,
(case when isnumeric(data)=1 Then
convert(float,data) else null end)
from mytable;
```

OR

```
select data, try_convert(float,data)
from mytable;
```

Here is the sample code:

```
create table mytable(data varchar(50));

insert into mytable values(65.98);
insert into mytable values(54);
insert into mytable values('xyz');
insert into mytable values(100.9876);

select data,
(case when isnumeric(data)=1 Then
convert(float,data) else null end)
from mytable;

select data, try_convert(float,data)
from mytable;
```

See the fiddle here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0a8295572f5b96f65f4fd56e39433afa

**Note:** For some inputs like `.` `isnumeric()` check does not work and hence `try_convert()` solution is recommended.

Comment: `isnumeric = 1` does not mean cast to float will work. Try `'.'`, for example.

Comment: You have a point. I'll recommend `try_convert()`. That works always.